# Numbering Theorem, definition, Proposition, Corollary, Remark by section consecutively without repetition

Tags: sectioning, numbering, sv-classes

I am writing a paper for publication in Springer journal using svjourclass, and I am using the following set of commands

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}

\documentclass[smallextended,envcountsect]{svjour3} 

\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
\usepackage{graphicx}  

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}% for appendix met A
\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{dcolumn}

\newcounter{chapter} % to fix the bug in svjour3
\usepackage{cleveref} 

\spnewtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]{\bfseries}{\itshape}  
\spnewtheorem{cor}[theorem]{Corollary}{\bfseries}{\itshape}
\spnewtheorem{lem}[theorem]{Lemma}{\bfseries}{\itshape}
\spnewtheorem{ntn}[theorem]{Notations}{\bfseries}{\itshape} 
\spnewtheorem{pro}[theorem]{Proposition}{\bfseries}{\itshape} 
\spnewtheorem{dfn}[theorem]{Definition}{\bfseries}{\itshape}   
\spnewtheorem{as}[theorem]{Assumption}{\bfseries}{\itshape}
\spnewtheorem{rem}[theorem]{Remark}{\bfseries}{\itshape}
\spnewtheorem{ob}[theorem]{Observation}{\bfseries}{\itshape}   

Now when I write with a \section{} for example 

\begin{dfn} 

\end{dfn} 

\begin{thm}  

\end{thm}



\begin{rem} 

\end{rem} 

\begin{lem} 

\end{lem} 


\begin{pro} 

\end{pro} 

\begin{cor} 

\end{cor}

\begin{pro}

\end{pro}

\begin{dfn}  

\end{dfn}
```

what I am getting is

Definition 2.1
Theorem 2.1
Remark 2.2
Lemma 2.3
Proposition 2.4
Corollary 2.5
Proposition 2.6
Definition 2.7

Now I am not sure why the numbering of the first two Definition and Theorem are being repeated. What I do actually want is just usual like

Definition 2.1

Theorem 2.2

Remark 2.3

Lemma 2.4

Proposition 2.5

Corollary 2.6

Proposition 2.7

Can someone please help me in getting the right code for such display?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have requested that the `cor`, `lem`, etc. environments be numbered like `theorem` and not `thm`.

That said, you should probably use the predefined environments provided by the class, rather than your own. Note, for example, that they specify different formatting for `remark`. See the [documentation](https://projects.mai.liu.se/BIT/usrguid3.pdf) for more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot; that worked out perfectly! Would you also happen to know how to give enumeration commands? When I write \begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*)]
   
    \item 
   
\end{enumerate}   it gives me the enumeration numbers (1) but in italics, but I do not want them in italics. Thanks

Comment: okay, I got it, just had to put [label=(\arabic*),font=\upshape]

Answer (score 0):

The numbering is presumably defined by the journal (you are using their recommended packages as directed, yes?). If so, the decision to number *just this way* is part of the journal's style, and trying to do it differently will just get your work rejected for not complying with the guidelines.